# Is it possible to stub(mock?) Ecto.UUID.generate in an ExUnit test?

Tags: unit-testing, elixir, ecto

I'm using `Ecto.UUID.generate` to create a random token on a user model.

In my **ExUnit** test, I want to test the controller that calls the creation route, however because the token is always random, I can't deterministically test the result.

Ideally, I want to be able to *stub* the `Ecto.UUID.generate` in my test so it always creates the same **UUID** so I can test the response correctly.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are mocking solutions in Elixir and Erlang but they are not used a lot. If you are further interested, here is an article: http://blog.29steps.co.uk/post/105715556278/testing-api-web-calls-in-elixir-using-meck

Honestly, I would just avoid the mock. If you have an API, test the returned ID is an UUID (you can see if `Ecto.UUID.dump(uuid)` returns `{:ok, something}`). If it is a browser/html app, it is likely you care about the UUID even less.

Comment: I'm currently just testing the length of it is what I expect. The reason I switch it when I do the route test is because the route returns JSON and I was just testing the complete JSON object is what I expect. Thanks for the article though, real good read! :)